# Remove smaller subset paths from the list of paths returned by the cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I remove smaller paths that are returned by the cypher which are already contained in other longer paths containted in the same result?

For example if my cypher is `MATCH path=(n)-[:REL*]->(m) where id(n)=<some id> return path`. Thus it returns all paths that contain any number of outgoing relationships of type `[:REL]`. However it returns multiple paths for a longer path (containing more than 2 nodes), each path containing path to the successive node in the longer path from the specified start node. For example, it may return following paths:

```
(a)-[:REL]->(b)
(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)
(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(f)
(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(d)
(a)-[:REL]->(c) 
(a)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(e)
```

As you can notice `(a)-[:REL]->(b)` is contained in all

- `(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(f)`
- `(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)` and
- `(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(d)`,

`(a)-[:REL]->(c)` is contained in `(a)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(e)`

`(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)` is contained in `(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(f)`

I dont want `(a)-[:REL]->(b)`, `(a)-[:REL]->(c)` and `(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)` to appear in the output as they are part of other paths.

Is this possible with cypher? Somehow I feel (though it feels weird to feel this), cypher should have allowed `!` (logical not) before relationship specification to imply that the relationship of particular type does not go out of (or come in) the node. I could have written:

```
MATCH path=(n)-[:REL*]->(m)!-[:REL]->() where id(n)=<some id> return path
```

This would have disallowed those smaller paths.

Anyways how can I do above in cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add filtering for this, returning only paths where the end node does not have an outgoing :REL relationship:

```
MATCH path=(n)-[:REL*]->(m) 
where id(n)=<some id> and not (m)-[:REL]->()
return path
```

Comment: yeah I need to practice cypher more...switching techs frequently not permitting me that :\